# Python : lxml xpath get two different classes

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Here is my sample Python code

```
import requests
import lxml.html

page = '<div class="aaaa12"><span class="test">22</span><span class="number">33</span></div><div class="dddd13"><span>Kevin</span></div>' 
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(page)


number = tree.xpath('//span[@class="number"]/text()')
price = tree.xpath('.//div[@class="dddd13"]/span/text()')

print number
print price
```

When I ran I could get like below

```
['33']
['Kevin']
```

However, I would like to get both at once like = ['33','Kevin']
I tried

```
number = tree.xpath('//span[@class="number"]/text() or //div[@class="dddd13"]/span/text()')
```

I couldn't get the value. What is syntax to get two different classes?

Comment: You have more than just two classes, your tags differ too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `|` union operator to join the results of multiple full path expressions:

```
number = tree.xpath('//span[@class="number"]/text() | //div[@class="dddd13"]/span/text()')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> page = '<div class="aaaa12"><span class="test">22</span><span class="number">33</span></div><div class="dddd13"><span>Kevin</span></div>' 
>>> tree = lxml.html.fromstring(page)
>>> tree.xpath('//span[@class="number"]/text() | //div[@class="dddd13"]/span/text()')
['33', 'Kevin']
```