# How to avoid overwriting output when passing more than one condition to lxml xpath?

Tags: python, parsing, xpath, lxml

Consider the below syntax:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring; from requests import get
url = some_url
fromstring(get(url).content).xpath("//tr//th//text()" and "//tr/td//text()")
```

This executes as expected. However I only get output stored for the second condition `"//tr/td//text()"` which I suspect is due to the second condition output overwriting the first condition output instead of storing both of them. I tried something like:

```
list1 = []
list1.append(fromstring(get(url).content).xpath("//tr//th//text()" and "//tr/td//text()")
```

but there is not difference in how this works. My question is how can I avoid the second output from overwriting the first one?

PS: I can always parse just the `content` and save the whole thing to memory and than sequentially get both the xpath conditions.

Something like

```
r = fromstring(get(url).content)
r1 = r.xpath("//tr//th//text()")
r2 = r.xpath("//tr/td//text()")
```

This solves the problem, but for a large project this can be memory inefficient as I will have to block more memory here to store the entire contents rather than just storing the elements that I am interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath should help `xpath("//tr//th//text() | //tr/td//text()")`. 
Also, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28562759/4900574) is for you

Comment: just one more thing, is there a way in which i can get the output in form of nested list? like: [[output xpath1],[output xpath2]]

Comment: Which data do you have in result list? You can try split or slice after xpath